# Mysql Query with multiple subqueries with group by distinct condition

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Hi I am a PHP Developer weak in MySQL Medium complex queries make my head fired.
The below is the table `vulnerability`.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| id | webisite_id | low_count| high_count | medium_count | date_time           |   vul_date    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 20 | 6           | 1        | 1          | 1            | 2018-07-04 09:14:04 | 2018-02-01    |
| 19 | 6           | 30       | 30         | 30           | 2018-07-04 09:13:38 | 2018-01-30    |   
| 18 | 6           | 1        | 1          | 1            | 2018-07-04 09:13:16 | 2018-01-01    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This table represent count of low, medium, high - vulnerability count for each website in database. We can enter as many entries for each websites. But the only relevant entry for a website is the latest entry in each month (based on `vul_date`).

Here I need help I want query which fetch sum of counts low, high, medium of each websites of each month of last 1 year, for example if -> website with `id` 1 has 1, 2, 3 low, high, medium number of vulnerabilities, on month June and 
 -> that of with `id` 2 has 7, 8, 9 respectively the result should be for June 8, 10, 12. And like last 1 year's each month result should be get. If no entry it should be 0.

Note that the entries should be the maximum value of `vul_date` and if a site has multiple entries on the same `vul_date` get the latest `date_time` entry.

I tried to write question as much as simple. hope the question is understood.
Please help me on this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So for each month you only wanna add up the latest entries based on vul_date column, so for majority of month, it will be just one entry right ? And which column is deriving the month entry date_time or vul_date ?

Comment: Why are the dates in date_time different to vul_date for site 6? eg 2018-07-04 09:14:04 | 2018-02-01 |

Comment: @P.Salmon actually date_time is time we adding the entry. and vul_date  is date which adding entry for . eg we can now add entry for a date of last week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below query will work for you.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(low_count),
    SUM(medium_count),
    SUM(high_count),
    MONTH(vul_date)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        low_count, medium_count, high_count, vul_date, date_time
    FROM
        test
    WHERE
        (website_id , vul_date) IN (SELECT website_id, MAX(vul_date)
            FROM test GROUP BY website_id , MONTH(vul_date))) t
WHERE
    date_time IN (SELECT MAX(date_time) FROM test GROUP BY website_id , vul_date)
GROUP BY MONTH(vul_date);
```

What it does is, first finds the latest entry month wise for each website id which is your max vul_date.

```
SELECT website_id, MAX(vul_date)
            FROM test GROUP BY website_id , MONTH(vul_date)
```

If there are more than one entry for a vul_date, it uses date_time to select maximum value from them. Finally it sums all website date after grouping it month wise.

You can change the above query to get 0 value for those months where there is no entry for any websites.

Comment: Thanks. I am almost there.. There is some my own customization required. You saved my lot of time.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T(id INT, website_id INT, low_count INT, high_count INT, medium_count INT, date_time DATETIME, vul_date DATE);
INSERT INTO T VALUES
( 20 , 6 , 1 , 1 , 1,  '2018-07-04 09:14:04' , '2018-02-01'), 
( 19 , 6 , 30, 30, 30, '2018-07-04 09:13:38' , '2018-01-30'), 
( 18 , 6 , 2 , 2 ,2 ,  '2018-07-04 09:13:16' , '2018-01-01'),
( 17 , 6 , 2 , 2 ,2 ,  '2018-07-04 09:12:01' , '2018-01-01'),
( 90 , 1,1,2,3,'2017-07-05 01:00:00',' 2017-07-06'),
( 90 , 2,8,9,10,'2017-07-05 01:00:00',' 2017-07-06');

select coalesce(c.yyyymm,d.yyyymm) yyyymm,
        coalesce(c.lo,0) lo,
        coalesce(c.hi,0) hi,
        coalesce(c.med,0) med 
from
(

SELECT concat(year(a.vul_date),'-',month(a.vul_date)) yyyymm,
        SUM(LOW_COUNT) lo,SUM(HIGH_COUNT) hi,sum(medium_count) med
from
(
select  website_id,date_time,vul_date
from t
where date_time = (select max(date_time) from t t1 where t1.website_id = t.website_id and t1.vul_date = t.vul_date)
) a
join
(select website_id, date_time,vul_date,
          LOW_COUNT,HIGH_COUNT,medium_count
from t) b
on b.website_id = a.website_id and b.date_time = a.date_time
group by concat(year(a.vul_date),'-',month(a.vul_date))
) c
right join 
(select distinct concat(year(dte),'-',month(dte)) yyyymm from dates d
where dte between date_sub(now(), interval 1 year) and now() 
) d on d.yyyymm = c.yyyymm
;
```

Sub query a get the vul_date with the most recent data_time which is then self joined, aggregated and then infilled with missing dates using a right join to a dates/calender table. If you don't have a dates/calender it would be useful for this kind of exercise nut there are alternatives which you can find in SO.

Result

```
+---------+------+------+------+
| yyyymm  | lo   | hi   | med  |
+---------+------+------+------+
| 2017-7  |    9 |   11 |   13 |
| 2017-8  |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2017-9  |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2017-10 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2017-11 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2017-12 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2018-1  |   32 |   32 |   32 |
| 2018-2  |    1 |    1 |    1 |
| 2018-3  |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2018-4  |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2018-5  |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2018-6  |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2018-7  |    0 |    0 |    0 |
+---------+------+------+------+
13 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```